# cypress can't test focus

Tags: focus, cypress

I am trying to test a keyboard shortcut that set focus on a field, it works on the browser, but cypress seems not to be able to test it.

```
    cy.get('body').type('{alt}E');
    cy.get('#fieldId').should('have.focus'); // fails.
```

In the cypress Chrome, I am unable to set focus on the field, even with the mouse. I click on the field and it just blinks but doesn't keep the focus.

Edited:

I discovered that there is a field stealing the focus. This field gets the focus when the page loads. When the cypress does the test on the desired field, the page is not completely loaded yet. When the page loads, then the focus passes to another field, and the test fails. How can I make cypress to wait until the page end loading to only then make the test on the desired field?

Comment: if you use cy.get('body').focus().type('{alt}E') does it work? 
could be helpful to have some code to debug

Comment: No, it didn't work, even after adding focus(). I'll try to make a simple example.

Comment: Sorry, every simple example worked as expected, I discovered that there is a field stealing the focus I want. How can I avoid it?